# Regex match everything up until sequence of characters

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, impala, regex-greedy, regex-group

I am trying to extract part of a json message but failing to write the correct regex.

Biggest problem is that the application I am writing this for (Impala - big data query engine) contains a bug preventing non-greedy operations using `?`, therefore I need a different solution.

Example

```
{"postcode":"ABCDEF","forename":"James","id":"{12}","surname":"Townsend"},
{"postcode":"HIJKLM","forename":"Toby","id":"{34}","surname":"Taylor"},
{"surname":"Reilly","postcode":"NOPQRS","forename":"Mike","id":"{56}"}
```

The data will be in this format all in one string (no line breaks) but inside each "section" the the data can be in any order.

I need to use regex to end up with the part of the message where the forename is "Toby"

```
{"postcode":"HIJKLM","forename":"Toby","id":"{34}","surname":"Taylor"}
```

currently I have

```
{[^{]*"forename":"Toby"[^}]*}
```

However this doesn't work work, what I need it to match `{"` and `"}` as the start and end.

Can anyone please offer advice on how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Smells like an X/Y problem.  That looks like (somewhat) well formed json.  Depending on the language being used (you don't tell us if you're regexing within, for example, a javascript function or a C# method), it probably would be better to load and iterate the json objects, simply examining the forename property.

Comment: I'm using Impala query engine which contains a "regexp_extract" method within a sql statement. syntax is regexp_extract(string initial, string pattern, string replacement) - link https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/impala_string_functions.html#string_functions__regexp_extract

Comment: However I'm currently using this site to try and get it initially working https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

Escape the leading/trailing curly brackets:

```
\{[^{]*"forename":"Toby"([^}]|\}(?="))*\}(?!")
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/dOxy9SrxvY).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately that answer doesn't include everything i need. I need the whole middle statement from the example. That live demo was useful to see the results you intended

Comment: @DataPro I didn't even notice that fail. I've improved it so it passes your example. It is possibly too brittle now as it specifically allows a `}` when followed by a `"` as content, however it may be enough to do your job.

Comment: Everything looked good until I used it in my application and got the following error: **Could not compile regexp pattern: `{[^{]*"forename":"Toby"([^}]|}(?="))*}(?!")` Error: invalid perl operator: (?=**           Any ideas? I dont know enough about specific regex languages

Comment: @DataPro I can see the problem. You didn't copy the regex from my answer accurately. You've omitted the backslash before the `}` that lies 8 characters after "Toby"

Comment: I copied your statement accurately but the reason they weren't showing was that in Impala to escape you use `//` rather than `/`. I did this and the error shows as **Could not compile regexp pattern: \{[^{]*"forename":"Toby"([^}]|\}(?="))*\}(?!") Error: invalid perl operator: (?=**

Comment: Seems like the flavour of regex it uses doesn't support it, however it does say in the documentation "For details, see the RE2 documentation. It has most idioms familiar from regular expressions in Perl, Python, and so on". However there is the known bug I mentioned above where non-greedy expressions using `?` do not work properly

Comment: @DataPro the most common feature *not* implemented is look arounds, and `(?=")` is one. I don't think it can be done using regex. Use a JSON parser.

Comment: @Bohemian I think I found a solution without look arounds but I'm not sure it works 100% - Edit: just realized that this is 16 days old ._.

Comment: @FabianN. Try it on a regex testing site and post the link in your answer (if it works).

Comment: @Bohemian Already done from the beginning, the question is more if my test string covers all edge cases.